# Bessel's Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I solve this Bessel's Equation?

$$x^2*y''+x*y'+(x^2-v^2)y=0$$

First I did that:

$$y''+\frac{1}{x}y'+\frac{(x^2-v^2)}{x^2}y = 0$$

Then,

$$ce^{-\int\left[\frac{1}{x}\right]dx}=ce^{-\ln(x)}=-cx$$

Comment: @mark-mcclure In the book it says Bessel's Equation

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that your textbook refers to your differential equation as Bessel's Equation.  I'm saying that there is a special function, called Bessel's Function, which solves Bessel's Equation.  The link I provided explains this in detail.

Comment: Even if your approach was correct, $\mathrm{e}^{-\ln(x)}\neq-x$ but instead it equals 1/x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x^2*y''+x*y'+(x^2-v^2)y=0$$
is the Bessel ODE which solutions are linear combinations of the Bessel functions of the first- and second- kind.

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselDifferentialEquation.html
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunctionoftheSecondKind.html